# difficulties with newdata in predict.coxph

Tags: r, predict, survival

I have a data.frame named "df" with structure

```
'data.frame':   800 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ status: num  1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 ...
 $ time  : num  4.97 1.53 3.98 2.75 3.86 ...
 $ uo    : chr  "C" "B" "C" "B" ...
 $ q3    : Factor w/ 4 levels "1","2","3","4": 4 1 1 3 3 3 2 3 2 1 ...
```

I implemented the following model:

```
 sm1<-with( df, Surv(time,status))
 mod<-coxph(sm1~q3+strata(uo),data=df)
```

and to predict

```
 new<-data.frame(q3=as.factor(rep(1:4,3)),uo=rep(LETTERS[1:3],each=4),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
 pred<-predict(mod,newdata=new,type="lp")
```

obtaining the following warning:

**Error in newx - xmeans[match(newstrat, row.names(xmeans)), ] : 
  array incompatibili**

The new data.frame has the same columns with the same names and the same structure  of original df data.frame

Anyone can help to detect what went wrong?

Thanks
Filippo Pinzone

Addendum: df structure

```
df<-structure(list(status = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1), time = c(4.97333938980073, 
1.5335568005848, 3.97779635439093, 2.7459845744055, 3.8588892334092, 
2.54603219837931, 2.23372017027795, 3.42909940372004, 0.546441584169012, 
3.42961103414892, 4.13547035553943, 2.38974577815685, 3.63257703315934, 
4.52600017937921, 5.66841141763255, 0.897149198268734, 2.85064324456642, 
8.42369773602478, 2.55650588307482, 4.49307137525081, 1.61965325022512, 
2.24141041229007, 5.35115751878801, 0.258364639095974, 5.50295673773204, 
2.64924689468436, 1.43746977225737, 3.1851375871176, 1.47733323600212, 
3.07032651520212, 1.54783508621948, 3.02572237015449, 4.31482324352246, 
5.20246701830851, 7.10539801632626, 1.26567689018055, 3.12634544718299, 
4.25817073628868, 2.36798185108861, 2.9415872287492, 1.26159759501473, 
2.12715698922699, 1.46897481995762, 2.11118622466991, 1.09062191276148, 
5.53411546789772, 4.21764686029, 5.17825583557616, 5.55419429184471, 
1.17404030675649, 1.88173317316144, 3.21247299265059, 4.68079893941827, 
1.16337110806226, 4.58779282982402, 3.22280916289992, 3.75453112814264, 
2.84206420672571, 7.5301126370096, 6.49208441463532, 10.695513943654, 
5.8395208500808, 5.40933926419788, 2.75480193582422, 0.232036271442484, 
3.28471030284603, 0.970477490873351, 10.6677636849117, 1.53263429007799, 
2.28397550058292, 4.52246455309742, 5.87194714078361, 6.40447839676533, 
2.92042689942323, 1.74279636791905, 2.72246832426798, 2.20236870315485, 
4.66574704994628, 2.42944647221066, 0.584719775125415, 5.49438815582561, 
4.98920493534394, 6.94483846692817, 1.21991782009358, 12.2612774225453, 
1.64387919962076, 3.11351158768676, 6.02012568402022, 2.84048913941756, 
15.1330748995984, 12.1532553821213, 7.92672786859241, 5.08613142306492, 
2.47404484270418, 7.97464891193322, 6.0469647581773, 4.37937394517663, 
7.21515646353254, 8.35511772464242, 4.78918650706861, 4.55511484971807, 
2.43018765368613, 11.6218101807436, 7.04887743930713, 2.20330867822245, 
5.27183289741261, 2.67647111516039, 4.56074798665169, 5.9444784699475, 
4.45711035011443, 4.70799208958061, 0.478733671056406, 4.77174241470581, 
0.638445565638134, 2.0033152229503, 2.09613287244764, 2.32206796500514, 
1.12157358389725, 2.57684767012914, 3.76339828436039, 3.35944316375514, 
1.52138900599624, 8.18334131390905, 1.30815978905887, 2.89759827956571, 
4.32935233740533, 2.6169313180985, 5.79338694507468, 1.58346536833831, 
1.36416573115472, 0.729274353109148, 4.52883210694683, 2.53861999340109, 
0.711496065019544, 3.57694428134625, 2.93288703148286, 2.69949327001632, 
10.9073168758137, 2.38964893629383, 0.784522150935863, 0.917719129812195, 
1.16153338023026, 10.8556870109642, 5.16056887885632, 2.79773973294734, 
0.239448302522359, 0.552483320069629, 4.30358195220292, 1.80990345275785, 
10.0741441631049, 4.05230712622791, 1.73895899546183, 7.49187585117715, 
3.20119937527713, 1.96434142394457, 2.90442854687277, 5.96785371755791, 
1.30546747441597, 6.72550362011612, 2.78267553128369, 4.25313779274921, 
2.38269966801516, 6.73393133307113, 0.558210326482197, 2.49815148950341, 
2.17892047603301, 0.924513298738884, 1.01890632150554, 6.57836879758667, 
6.50959091432832, 1.57978803363102, 6.78058228909186, 6.60969378451032, 
1.36624352472366, 3.77563978314332, 12.3147495852871, 4.344141629899, 
2.34614362257354, 4.98527919274234, 0.250379317939442, 1.68659970881051, 
1.64486262928058, 5.97297429582734, 3.24693931530993, 3.69848413596598, 
1.28965490878654, 4.34319392730232, 2.4300951507915, 1.01900159400292, 
5.02331626579938, 11.7958163595454, 1.19443685602643, 4.00663015830792, 
3.15563015469039, 3.23557324973888, 1.87059284996961, 0.974468130641005, 
4.18313507157774, 3.09022335202376, 1.44099913532813, 2.53458417957297, 
1.97055726795722, 2.50101354499647, 3.78864823676202, 2.53637902922, 
1.53516481622766, 5.5494873742668, 4.93757131382843, 9.03183961898586, 
7.92719838695367, 2.79436056944306, 3.54634659528636, 5.82005008764274, 
2.92334496558043, 7.36935681431828, 1.88280791615011, 1.59664782914012, 
1.50999081109823, 3.2848928495097, 8.29326088011051, 4.88349165934706, 
2.36392489250064, 5.62949622162709, 4.19409584212047, 1.0110482568435, 
2.31927680378298, 2.82480731369777, 1.56517851828597, 7.24971807133916, 
0.829169729440521, 2.09386644856128, 6.85504925962267, 2.26150539508476, 
1.23210624568455, 2.35281031403866, 2.24055952330054, 3.36421249239156, 
4.62450323894486, 1.04432313630089, 5.89396982035102, 2.98855018793204, 
2.10174197639314, 2.53178283132995, 4.47271283589583, 4.87405089931884, 
1.17458697202677, 3.09115357775752, 5.36053281477551, 2.61356986062052, 
6.59608262114562, 3.75434251811432, 2.08412444622161, 1.57563356754269, 
2.55355421619461, 3.57042607008839, 3.58215130001775, 2.78648121403054, 
5.49364524520188, 0.938822540723013, 11.2117992638984, 5.6582703693369, 
2.37018488322802, 6.16398745209939, 4.63345084391602, 11.9062759572664, 
1.15486887349439, 3.18742097243976, 8.09339911495526, 2.52486057059614, 
13.4825287195645, 1.21356114699196, 0.487674946141541, 2.67727320121588, 
3.03206595620159, 2.02523552830679, 2.55518058776725, 5.36631627367668, 
2.85154821154558, 1.2584040301746, 2.84936179753485, 2.18107201866382, 
13.3610926943359, 2.18412942608593, 5.17702238298993, 2.26434331256917, 
6.8028671075932, 6.33021266811788, 6.81869638768773, 3.07019352354636, 
4.02610076344082, 2.87797086192996, 1.71173187482801, 5.64303778801614, 
2.34816329101694, 4.19781601089903, 4.34660352234979, 6.92556031472862, 
1.70079695562932, 2.44360251089508, 3.27716302266907, 3.66708131153233, 
5.14829470388404, 10.2968082872314, 9.28258455866619, 1.28115586003516, 
4.05820195533115, 1.32995820931616, 3.83118266518891, 4.19223565759026, 
2.23670673495512, 5.78123989323499, 1.20519107125836, 3.31906180047893, 
5.57522904002357, 9.88400688715062, 2.28672258783489, 7.85115678670894, 
14.2200214563425, 2.59701339817347, 5.5989948811727, 5.63389155633252, 
3.08089324615275, 4.09807044297088, 3.17641431363988, 3.20210479479866, 
6.94493696105099, 5.63535378863042, 2.55250405045381, 5.41075450789042, 
4.24879289151705, 1.11872295735813, 4.97614880927324, 5.56317169195685, 
2.52554961792447, 4.32681714828322, 6.97984447763177, 6.42478588910944, 
3.13202386443558, 1.83420326444323, 2.59001179988748, 3.75404904679969, 
5.49803867925996, 4.16572609512504, 6.62360206226511, 2.91864584268819, 
3.69138816264487, 1.03323818452478, 3.54174678516976, 0.872687191172139, 
5.42797419750798, 3.69704790991688, 3.09762970448858, 7.91637054098947, 
3.0653080122318, 1.79483674118795, 9.52157952723237, 3.93621744480171, 
1.19380760905972, 5.63382297815454, 8.00639923803025, 1.68301323228101, 
1.69266506310382, 10.1604729917291, 2.05110261532289, 8.99880038903165, 
4.59213588460788, 4.77367513168615, 4.37431895771824, 2.98925796165504, 
5.78730996974533, 3.39723793855531, 3.79361883273039, 4.84005678890227, 
2.49073443624692, 3.87665749337819, 2.01993041503586, 2.6609506868186, 
3.97139106514012, 7.12775391994435, 3.58674062403169, 4.5527723729946, 
3.30742148745068, 1.29188695630562, 4.24446327211851, 5.16959974997227, 
2.101469242662, 4.83535168499691, 2.25257082744031, 2.17534386414855, 
3.2254958435386, 3.76697061643146, 3.65801076907159, 4.48291456601304, 
2.95020559771972, 5.28912161990108, 4.54029179993457, 1.3418521338625, 
0.0897623328914826, 16.9962498447271, 2.12690878121351, 7.51139843977287, 
2.47666803375945, 4.99648274122862, 1.56233887820074, 1.38136603983559, 
0.155178983099641, 1.70184301118046, 1.5720042092357, 1.69064648520372, 
4.63379928917765, 5.11105399593146, 3.11429585281072, 4.93952413844212, 
3.21567230220153, 1.91100541700415, 0.662271342161362, 1.65017676189614, 
5.34024163519205, 3.63853135242179, 2.75822071399584, 2.36661847266081, 
5.83077956944108, 2.56694823227818, 2.58603074376354, 3.73967213308943, 
3.53185528262397, 5.34014743571844, 1.08711761884207, 4.8035364125759, 
1.89856020474986, 7.2526880015147, 3.04090703104415, 1.83542437870837, 
2.02085738387621, 9.26829251385166, 3.0789933186886, 1.43347949824926, 
4.51700667336142, 2.07933812405148, 2.59463370031276, 4.4801695435147, 
3.62564044621035, 1.78886426807493, 3.74726432907792, 4.85761879907147, 
6.70845536847072, 3.03012669774155, 2.75750205877149, 3.57059770014809, 
2.24175208319529, 1.54220615159515, 6.8878057895963, 0.59322516545957, 
0.65759345835736, 3.5684167292072, 1.83268607298977, 4.3875298591259, 
3.19844355603511, 3.74932028844198, 1.55224689100904, 1.60302359172329, 
3.60187370085982, 7.51473277947895, 2.93705363812913, 8.00156923813454, 
3.63999681692451, 7.15183829237543, 2.99861086730484, 1.87390763944794, 
2.20840659258449, 4.56420566284895, 4.07721754117501, 7.09698290480335, 
0.250164347243068, 9.48683570151372, 11.1617337966307, 2.85600229386903, 
6.86413384213203, 1.73630719460527, 4.80213858651884, 1.9840443043739, 
9.92722106245147, 4.10326454989323, 2.5716654742118, 4.54358678505981, 
6.39369575259791, 1.25000049047901, 2.23566710261773, 3.51349463043031, 
5.28935632276197, 3.97808453206673, 1.00011826394619, 1.03556085321542, 
11.360813650895, 1.64453847391372, 6.42938769333359, 3.69838786443919, 
1.2880572956004, 0.818953637739523, 5.01303412505493, 2.77536145016216, 
1.72021775346172, 1.28306357394055, 5.92266607297087, 2.57359836040086, 
8.52934505915043, 4.0402733048321, 1.88003183595396, 0.911284709903278, 
8.15542963079085, 5.61727633543604, 5.60140395373245, 3.0535417784328, 
3.80759675583809, 1.30543259887939, 4.47161425863487, 2.30532641868192, 
2.34057341216194, 2.63766279394503, 3.08107625370275, 3.21447359170919, 
1.51098015104067, 4.85194582532855, 2.0145476376917, 5.06253161935444, 
0.633576604819942, 3.39824701906281, 1.68880196223391, 1.10129599458616, 
0.177022877301363, 1.48473716940792, 3.68783069765713, 4.9080865492735, 
3.57114201625991, 4.69872670790151, 4.06425122071399, 7.24000780778425, 
6.08209013413633, 1.10008315966666, 20.2882114816818, 1.98151208128099, 
13.517198616697, 8.27409097364167, 7.71622380387201, 1.92637448398858, 
5.77246612430791, 3.49452052729179, 0.233913772367004, 6.18266093205166, 
7.89370934023424, 3.32422757842585, 7.32082448916015, 5.12868640116491, 
9.00262744344587, 7.03373372645696, 2.71065218798216, 2.58906078070969, 
6.2406854859297, 13.2065356016851, 5.05005324868936, 1.14844324043248, 
2.71866031509975, 0.379600924833675, 8.83635120520931, 1.83626401272652, 
5.50181506467725, 5.8113701584654, 1.63435781741955, 2.95549323742937, 
6.49346692029685, 1.79601252698322, 7.22757397403681, 3.20977642519426, 
5.07385929784836, 7.77827871894427, 3.19275560838773, 12.6387183622938, 
4.79872099437098, 1.66794057044374, 4.62781811278843, 6.18868578937358, 
5.19844114462199, 1.21077001334726, 6.14389609215006, 1.24330323064631, 
2.06708418424824, 5.33149481215217, 5.13126175079739, 3.7909522336775, 
5.08280833703051, 2.35801547133798, 5.56619528649812, 2.52845932942388, 
5.64212979843821, 2.6590568735876, 0.259272384702883, 6.00025446130812, 
3.30718063340448, 4.11343841419697, 0.193323044275211, 7.56157001995764, 
0.980095850659066, 6.0107581960221, 4.38139970239457, 2.85056830282552, 
1.19369247389523, 0.929256188536516, 2.57833959372943, 4.21211797373067, 
0.408059982520225, 2.57202258750142, 1.57313749046432, 0.590058162093862, 
4.04595791861277, 8.15757617816833, 6.19708236197112, 6.42133493809097, 
7.24384885175622, 1.66145611548349, 8.42385085644063, 1.78215596699336, 
3.19182146448003, 2.38313418055845, 1.22220520788241, 4.47582991923519, 
4.91272441800412, 1.4824369494966, 8.13855769044995, 3.06280164993728, 
0.487630014817591, 3.29177009963812, 0.724981593065381, 3.05462674248277, 
10.8788952130521, 0.919054794572684, 1.70022647469967, 9.87332722560451, 
3.11588066213563, 0.962227981399471, 5.25114208778676, 4.30342951754965, 
7.95715751659932, 0.684626575551653, 2.20506904267448, 11.2515810893868, 
7.01830551935693, 1.31247150670459, 8.84532354238389, 9.47152701640563, 
1.35856211893161, 2.12545413807233, 1.71729183424993, 1.49909126666628, 
1.38215870951835, 7.2409648216671, 2.08210126766111, 7.12008489425891, 
4.22991813220844, 3.01904035733167, 3.06503296679787, 2.49403278265912, 
3.3160541689467, 1.73900938691184, 5.14506332872465, 3.90614329580425, 
2.75837960046978, 4.72984749763378, 9.6912640721937, 4.45749678287653, 
0.900680631203918, 10.4519302635709, 4.57427396167271, 10.3889369316313, 
2.08152482451535, 2.82885420745709, 5.61594292865414, 2.83937273478828, 
0.965708997216683, 2.67614106156811, 2.40706858382392, 0.837537990866297, 
4.63379635636901, 1.13044389676465, 2.56102616236792, 5.11885834111707, 
4.95553895792153, 5.8256551752206, 3.07491114543443, 11.1054606317011, 
0.635041416930421, 1.80411379474091, 5.57525814478015, 4.64922625882047, 
3.92480127777337, 1.66125940649602, 2.48606282223643, 2.04289366788992, 
5.74484093576953, 1.41266727340194, 0.490311768972553, 1.96093173429824, 
4.63716757470009, 7.62078634917092, 2.51266643733625, 9.06912849378012, 
4.9457761401931, 2.64590409368187, 4.59690012851928, 1.76765193505063, 
9.23709508248924, 6.35501674171384, 1.22103383545264, 2.96480703502878, 
4.48783174804656, 0.456137994851575, 3.49003530879005, 7.44148383909282, 
1.04192877230849, 6.2249476959046, 5.2591730271032, 2.06887890240621, 
1.63023486386103, 1.78106271525285, 3.19134611937137, 2.65017544879692, 
7.904713247698, 2.87001098614539, 6.52829856092301, 4.74099933989549, 
2.16235638692237, 5.33392965905542, 2.08231249256378, 6.30672627694159, 
6.30916514402266, 3.15707578331759, 3.90762211046578, 1.24081147703082, 
2.70943646092296, 5.75837593653837, 1.41393765283164, 4.20912657664402, 
3.57171871711402, 14.1575149244147, 6.08447434725717, 5.68272466880187, 
2.38284360063748, 4.52706432093583, 5.00432987312186, 1.37895349732368, 
6.02269959526416, 6.73353965026751, 1.43915592711916, 3.57585336025846, 
1.97715353497321, 2.75769946570811, 4.28217799296748, 1.39554317996524, 
3.13360988092948, 4.71110424346046, 2.67964170421195, 2.99372690010447, 
1.9289475466796, 3.00792278832052, 0.798065700948247, 2.45720678002809, 
1.94277580308899, 0.981822967256262, 5.94925042626186, 7.68642343976035, 
1.83629330250319, 6.1196314641903, 15.6486818919537, 4.05171557749977, 
1.97843479971945, 1.45479536669226, 9.48521002890528, 1.60268988182326, 
5.92675054606929, 4.32264259966141, 7.44182367197277, 4.38933463672153, 
5.82234974856734, 7.3127207071843, 4.29894260693699, 10.9756225697668, 
11.7115166321232, 0.75032407528675, 2.47212017931738, 1.29234048801447, 
11.2066822359374, 2.27551434371306, 0.973634469430681, 1.86384151732567, 
1.75754742737153, 3.38235081963136, 12.3128541873023, 0.127401995820925, 
2.53038521138808, 7.65475581833248, 3.50148205173299), uo = c("C", 
"B", "C", "B", "A", "B", "C", "A", "A", "A", "A", "C", "C", "B", 
"A", "A", "B", "B", "A", "C", "C", "C", "A", "C", "A", "B", "C", 
"B", "C", "C", "A", "B", "B", "A", "A", "A", "C", "C", "B", "A", 
"A", "C", "A", "A", "A", "B", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "C", "A", 
"B", "A", "C", "B", "C", "A", "A", "A", "B", "A", "C", "B", "A", 
"C", "C", "B", "A", "B", "C", "A", "A", "C", "B", "B", "A", "C", 
"A", "A", "C", "A", "B", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "A", "A", "C", 
"A", "A", "A", "B", "A", "B", "B", "B", "A", "C", "B", "A", "B", 
"A", "A", "C", "B", "A", "B", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "C", "A", 
"C", "C", "C", "A", "A", "B", "A", "C", "C", "A", "A", "C", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "A", "B", "A", "C", "C", "A", "C", "A", 
"C", "A", "A", "A", "C", "A", "A", "C", "A", "A", "B", "C", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "C", "B", "A", "A", "A", "C", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "C", "A", "C", "C", "C", "B", "A", "C", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"C", "B", "B", "B", "A", "B", "A", "C", "B", "A", "C", "B", "B", 
"C", "C", "C", "B", "C", "A", "B", "A", "C", "C", "A", "B", "A", 
"C", "B", "C", "A", "A", "B", "B", "A", "C", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"C", "C", "C", "A", "C", "C", "A", "A", "B", "C", "B", "A", "A", 
"A", "C", "C", "A", "B", "A", "A", "C", "A", "A", "C", "A", "A", 
"C", "A", "B", "B", "B", "A", "B", "C", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", 
"C", "B", "C", "C", "C", "B", "A", "A", "A", "C", "A", "A", "C", 
"C", "B", "B", "C", "C", "B", "B", "B", "C", "A", "A", "C", "B", 
"A", "B", "A", "C", "A", "C", "B", "C", "C", "A", "A", "B", "A", 
"C", "A", "C", "A", "B", "A", "C", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "C", "B", "C", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "A", 
"C", "A", "B", "C", "C", "A", "B", "B", "C", "B", "A", "C", "B", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"B", "B", "A", "C", "B", "C", "A", "C", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", 
"B", "B", "A", "A", "B", "C", "B", "B", "A", "C", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "C", "B", "C", "C", "B", "B", "C", "A", "A", 
"B", "B", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "C", "B", "C", "A", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "B", "B", "B", "B", "A", "B", "B", "A", 
"A", "C", "C", "B", "C", "A", "C", "A", "A", "A", "C", "A", "A", 
"A", "C", "C", "C", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "B", "C", "B", 
"B", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "A", "A", 
"B", "B", "B", "A", "A", "C", "B", "B", "B", "B", "A", "B", "C", 
"C", "A", "A", "C", "A", "C", "B", "C", "B", "B", "B", "A", "A", 
"A", "B", "C", "B", "A", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "C", "C", "A", 
"A", "B", "C", "A", "C", "C", "A", "C", "C", "B", "B", "B", "A", 
"B", "A", "C", "C", "A", "A", "A", "C", "C", "A", "A", "C", "A", 
"B", "B", "A", "B", "B", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "A", "C", 
"A", "A", "B", "A", "B", "C", "B", "B", "B", "A", "A", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "A", "A", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", 
"C", "A", "A", "C", "A", "A", "C", "A", "A", "C", "A", "C", "C", 
"C", "B", "C", "B", "A", "B", "B", "A", "C", "A", "A", "C", "B", 
"A", "A", "C", "A", "A", "B", "A", "C", "C", "A", "A", "A", "B", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "A", "A", "B", "B", "A", "A", "A", "B", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "B", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "A", "B", "B", "A", 
"A", "C", "B", "C", "A", "A", "A", "A", "C", "B", "A", "B", "A", 
"A", "C", "C", "C", "B", "A", "C", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "C", 
"B", "A", "A", "B", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "A", "B", "A", "A", 
"B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "A", "C", "C", "B", "A", "B", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "B", "A", "B", "C", "C", "A", "A", "C", "B", "B", "B", 
"A", "B", "B", "B", "A", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "A", "C", "C", 
"A", "B", "B", "A", "B", "C", "C", "C", "A", "A", "A", "C", "A", 
"A", "C", "C", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "A", 
"B", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "A", "C", "B", "B", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "A", "A", "A", "C", "C", "A", "B", "B", 
"B", "C", "A", "A", "A", "A", "C", "A", "A", "B", "C", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "C", "C", "B", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", 
"B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "A", "B", "B", "A", "C", "C", "A", "B", 
"C", "A", "A", "B", "B", "A"), q3 = structure(c(4L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 
1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 
4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 
3L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 
4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 
3L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 
2L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 
2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 
2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 
4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 
2L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 
3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 
4L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L,      
4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L), .Label = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("status", "time", 
"uo", "q3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 800L))
```